# Applescript and Mail in macOS Sierra: broken feature?

Tags: email, applescript, apple-mail, signatures

I guess you can't make a signature in Mail using AppleScript anymore?

If you're running Sierra, give this simple script a try:

```
tell application "Mail" to make new signature with properties {name:"My Signature"}
```

All I get is "Mail got an error. AppleEvent handler failed."

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the "AppleEvent handler failed" error occurs on many other occasions when running AppleScript on MacOs Sierra. I cannot delete mailboxes for instance:  [applescript can't delete any mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938557/applescript-cant-delete-any-mailbox)