# applescript can't delete any mailbox

Tags: applescript, macos-sierra

how to delete a mailbox?

```
tell application "Mail"
    delete mailbox "complaints" of account "ACME LLC"
end tell
```

gives me error "AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000"
MacOs Sierra 10.12

It is not a problem of file permission because renaming mailboxes works fine

Comment: Is this with macOS Sierra?  I have had multiple problems with my Mail scripts since the latest update, and have filed Bug Reports.

Comment: yes, updated post.

Comment: two updates later (MacOS 10.12.2) this bug is still not fixed. Booh Apple!